# having issues aligning my 3 cards properly on small screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

My issue is with alignment of element when they reach breakpoint of 1199 I noticed the style breaks even though i have justify content so the cards should be stacked together, I used mx-auto, but it does work, so idk I noticed  that my bootstrap card cols are taking a bit of space and thus tried to align the cards the same way I did with texts in a grid but they do not work idk i want when i reach lg breakpoint for cards to be stacked evenly in the middle not the way they're appearing, I can achieve this using padding but I feel like it is not the best way or the right way , just something feels off.

```css
.wrapper3 {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  background-color: red;
  /*padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;*/
}
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cardStyle {
  max-width: 380px;
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: #2e2d2c;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  wrapper3 {
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .cardStyle {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2e2d2c;
  }
}





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AJ</title>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="about">
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper3">
        <div class="text-center my-5">
          <h1 class="display-1 text-white my-5">
            Blog on <span class="text-warning fw-medium">medium</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div
          class="card-container"
          style="background-color: green; width: 100%"
        >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-4 mx-auto">
              <div class="card cardStyle rounded-0 text-white">
                <img
                  src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:750/format:webp/1*NF1u0378i1-dt2OrzAzhlA.jpeg"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="guy wielding a soward"
                />
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title my-2">
                    The 3 Worst Enemies of Human Potential and How to Combat
                    them
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text my-4">
                    We all have our abilities and talents that if used fully has
                    the potential to help us lead the kind of life we aspire to
                    live"...
                  </p>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="btn btn-warning rounded-0"
                    style="background-color: "
                    >Read More</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-4 mx-auto mx-lg-auto">
              <div class="card cardStyle rounded-0 text-white">
                <img
                  src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:828/format:webp/1*vSa-09NYjRTrj7dEQv1GAw.jpeg"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="..."
                />
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title my-2">
                    7 strategies to help you achieve your goals and fight off
                    procrastination
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text my-4">
                    We all have aspirations and dreams, but what hinders us from
                    reaching our goals? A significant obstacle to
                    productivity...
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-4 me-lg-auto">
              <div class="card cardStyle rounded-0 text-white">
                <img
                  src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:828/format:webp/1*HHy3RDE8QcRsDpMrKLUvIQ.jpeg"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="..."
                />
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title my-2">
                    6 Reasons Why Sensitive High Achievers Should Start
                    Journaling
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text my-4">
                    Are you a big-picture person, needing to understand the
                    'why' for better commitment? Do you struggle to articulate
                    thoughts or...
                  </p>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<img>` and [all self-closing HTML tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#start-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the cards width which I defined in my css file, right, then now the card  width is 100% by default so the cards take up all space with padding thanks to the container , still the card size isn't good, cuz i want them stacked next to each other , so that's where grid system with breakpoints in bootstrap helped solve that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).